# ¿Cómo se puede repetir un prompt con una condición?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente código. Si la contraseña es fallida al ingresarla, se debería repetir, y si vuelve a fallar que el proceso de `password = prompt("La contraseña es incorrecta, inténtelo una vez más");` debería volver a repetirse hasta que la contraseña es posible. ¿Cómo se puede hacer para que se repita hasta que se acierte? Gracias de antemano

```js
var password = prompt("Ingrese la contraseña");

 if(password == "hola") {
  alert("Contraseña correcta");
 } else {
  password = prompt("La contraseña es incorrecta, inténtelo una vez más");
   if(password == "hola") {
    alert("La contraseña es correcta");
   } else {
    // Aquí se repite el proceso password = prompt("La contraseña es incorrecta, inténtelo una vez más");
 }
}
```

Comment: No creo que repetir hasta acertar sea un buen diseño, ya que si no la recuerdas sería muy molesto tener un `prompt` siempre en vez de poder salir e intentar otra cosa. Tal como lo tienes si que se puede considerar un diseño *amigable*. Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea repetir un cuadro `prompt` indefinidamente o hasta que la entrada coincida con la variable almacenada en el sistema (contraseña).

**SOLUCIÓN**

Como te dije en mi comentario, no parece un diseño amigable el tener un cuadro de [`prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) indefinido o hasta que se acierte con la contraseña. El detalle está en que esta lógica es bloqueante y no se podrá ejecutar otro proceso hasta que no se satisfaga la condición.

Una forma de lograrlo es usando un bucle [`while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/while) y una sentencia de comparación dentro del mismo, así como la sentencia `break`.

Por ejemplo (usando una linea):

```js
const password = 'NoLoAdivinarasNunca';

while(true) if(prompt('Introduzca la contraseña:') === password) break;
```

De esta forma tendrás un molesto `prompt` hasta que introduzcas la contraseña correcta.

**Edición**

Puedes establecer una acción por defecto al resultado del `prompt`. Digamos que el valor sea una cadena que será como una instrucción especial para cancelar el bucle. Este valor es `null` y es devuelto como resultado de presionar `cancelar` en el `prompt`.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const password = 'NoLoAdivinarasNunca';

while(true) {
  let userInput = prompt('Introduzca la contraseña:');
  if(userInput === password) {
    alert('Contraseña correcta');
    break;
  }
  if(userInput === null) {
    alert('Se presionó CANCEL');
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Y se puede realizar una acción si se pulsa cancelar?

Comment: Si, claro, puedes parar el bucle, te edito mi respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar un `while` para hacer algo hasta que se cumpla cierta condición. En este caso, te interesa que salga el `prompt` si la contraseña no es igual a `hola`.

Si la contraseña es igual la condición no se cumple, por lo tanto, el bloque `while` no se ejecuta.

```js
var password = prompt("Ingrese la contraseña");

while(password !== "hola") {
  password = prompt("La contraseña es incorrecta, inténtelo una vez más");
}

alert("Contraseña correcta");
```

**EDIT** Como tener en cuenta la acción cancelar?

Cuando se cancela un `prompt` el valor que devuelve es `null`. Por lo tanto, la condición que puedes poner en el `while` es la siguiente.

```
while(password !== null && password !== "hola") {}
```

Si lo haces así tienes que tener en cuenta que el `alert("Contraseña correcta");` se ejecutará siempre.

Te propongo este *approach*

```
var password = prompt("Ingrese la contraseña");

if (password !== null) {
  // se ejecuta cuando no se haya dado a "Cancelar"
  while (password !== "hola") {
    password = prompt("La contraseña es incorrecta, inténtelo una vez más");
  }

  alert("Contraseña correcta");
}
```

Comment: ¿Y se puede realizar una acción si se pulsa cancelar?

Comment: he actualizado mi respuesta